# I cannot save values to firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to work with firebase in my android studio but somehow when it comes to save values in firebase database it simply does not work.

1. I do have user permission in manifest for internet and access network state
2. When i register throught the app user using this code

   ```
   if (password.equals(passwordConfirm)) {
   mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   //sign in success
                   Context context = getApplicationContext();

                   //creating user in database
                   String role = "user";
                   UserModel newUser = new UserModel(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid(), email,name, role, secondName);
                   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                   DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");
                   myRef.setValue(newUser);

                   Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);




               }
   ```

User does apper on firebase authentication list but database remains empty
I have log message "D/register: createUserWithEmail:success"

So I tried example straight from firebase which is

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

But it's not working as well

1. Firebase assistant in android studio says my app is connected to firebase and Dependencies are set up correctly
2. firebase rules are open so anyone can save anything for now, there are no error messages about permission in console

To be honest I'm kinda out of ideas why and how to fix it so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Is Email+Password method enabled/allowed in auth settings?

Comment: Thanks for reminder about tags, I will remember that for future. About auth settings, yes it's enabled and it's the only option for now. I see new users on the list when i register them, it's just database which is empty at all, I can't put any value there even with exmaple code. Can i somehow detach firebase and attach new one? Maybe something went wrong becouse everything else looks fine?

Comment: if you have multiple projects, like a live vs production  - ensure you are reading the values in the correct console or try fetching and printing the data after the write. it may be a simple case of user error. - Additionally, it would help to log any errors that may occur if something is actually failing. it should return them.

Comment: Indeed I had multiple projects and the only solution that came into my mind was to delete few projects and reattach current project to completly new project. I checked all  but in non of them there was values I pushed into database. Anyway deleting few of them and attach to new database fixed issue (still weird thought becouse I saw in which project there was authentication done and it should be the same one?)